# Ransack does not take params into consideration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I'm trying to create a search form for an object called `Space`. I have tried using a lot of `if` and `elsif`'s and I realized that it would not work so I started checking out Ransack. Seems great, if one could just get it to work.

The thing is, I have my form on my first page, `home#index`. In all tutorials the form is on the same page as the results will be shown at, I want to go to `spaces#index` instead, so here is my code...

Home (index.html.erb)

```
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
    <%= search_form_for @q, class: "form-inline" do |f| %>
        <div class="input-append">
            <%= f.label :city %>
            <%= f.search_field :city %>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

HomeController.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @q = Space.search(params[:q])
  @spaces = Space.all
  @spaceimages = Spaceimage.all
  @spacetypes = @spaces.select(:spacetype).distinct
  end
end
```

SpacesController.rb

```
def index
  @q = Space.search(params[:q])
  @spaces = @q.result
end
```

And this is what the server gets:

```
Started GET "/spaces?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bcity%5D=Gothenburg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-04 21:32:44 +0100
Processing by SpacesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>{"city"=>"Gothenburg"}}
  Space Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `spaces`.* FROM `spaces`
  Rendered spaces/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 50.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

So the params are there but `@spaces.search` (or `.ransack`) does not do anything with the query. Why?

Comment: Have you tried using some of the form helpers like `f.search_field :city_eq`. Also do you have an implmentation of `self.ransackable_attributes` in your `Space` model? (If not this is fine but if so please post as this can cause ransack to ignore search parameters.

Comment: Actually, that is exactly what it was! _cont or similiar has to be added to the  search_field, otherwise it will not take it. Thanks a bunch! :) @engineersmnky

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else looking at this:
Make sure that predicates are passed in as keys for the query hash, even if you have model.ransackable_attributes defined.

like so (first_name_cont is the predicate here):

```
>> User.ransack(first_name_cont: 'Rya').result.to_sql
=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."first_name" LIKE '%Rya%')
```